# Resolve service with Autofac and IHostBuilder

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, autofac

I have a MVVM wpf app in which i'm trying to implement dependency injection with Autofac.

App.xaml.cs :

```cs
public App(){
    // getting config path here
    ...

    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                   .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                   .AddJsonFile(configFilePath, optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                   .Build();

    // Host builder
    host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
       .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
       .ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>(builder =>
        {
            builder.RegisterModule(new ConfigurationModule(config));
            builder.RegisterType<MyService>().As<IMyService>();
            builder.RegisterType<MainViewModel>().As<IMainViewModel>();
            builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient()).As<HttpClient>();
            _containerBuilder = builder;
        })
       .Build();
}
```

Then on App startup i want to set my view model datacontext

```cs
protected override async void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{ 
    await host.StartAsync();

    // How to get a reference to my container or scope here to be able to resolve IMainViewModel ?
    var container = ...
    var mainVM = container.Resolve<IMainViewModel>();
    var window = new MainWindow { DataContext = mainVM };
    window.Show();

    base.OnStartup(e);

}
```

How can i resolve my MainViewModel in OnStartup method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service provider from [`IHost`](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions/IHost.cs,18) can be used to resolve main view model

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

//...

protected override async void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e) { 
    await host.StartAsync();

    IServiceProvider services = host.Services;
            
    IMainViewModel mainVM = services.GetService<IMainViewModel>();

    var window = new MainWindow { DataContext = mainVM };
    window.Show();

    base.OnStartup(e);

}
```

It will call the Autofac container under the hood. The service provider is just an abstraction on top of the Autofac container since

```
.UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
```

was invoked.

Comment: Getting this with your suggestion :
`The non-generic method 'IServiceProvider.GetService(Type)' cannot be used with type arguments`

Comment: @Narthe You are most likely missing a `using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` for dependency injection. The generic [`GetService<>`](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions/ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.cs) is an extension method

Comment: Should i do that even if i'm using dependency injection from Autofac ?
`using Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection;`

Comment: @Narthe Yes. it will call the autofac container under the hood. The service provider is just an abstraction on top of the autofac container

Comment: Thank you, I was getting confused between the two.